# Why does my Sun JVM fail to initialize when I set PermGen above 128M?

Tags: tomcat, permgen

I need to increase my PermGen. Currently I pass the following as command line parameters:

`-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`

This works. If I try to increase the values, however, my JVM fails to initialize, giving me this error:

`[2009-06-18 01:39:44] [info] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[2009-06-18 01:39:44] [info] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
[2009-06-18 01:39:44] [info] 
[2009-06-18 01:39:44] [395  javajni.c] [error] CreateJavaVM Failed`

Specifically, I'm trying to boot up *Tomcat* in the included *JRE6*, but I don't think this should matter.

**Edit:** I'm running Win2k3 VM image with 2GB of RAM. I boot the JVM using the *Monitor Tomcat* application with the following parameters:

Initial memory pool: **1024**, maximum memory pool: **1536**

`-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\tomcat\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf\logging.properties`

Comment: What is the operating system? How much memory the machine has? How much do you allocate for the heap and stack size (Xmx Xms Xss)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perm Gen is additive to Heap, so check the processes -- you'll need to have 1.5+ GB of your 2G available.

Comment: I didn't know the two were linked and this was my problem. I had maxed out my Heap size so there wasn't any room to increase PermGen. When I scaled back my Heap size I was then able to increase my PermGen space.

Answer (score 4):

Try to give it a bigger heap with -Xmx512m (this will give 512 MB)

What other memory parameters do you use? How much memory is there in your machine? Are you on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine?

Comment: That makes sense, since your 128MB perm size are part of the heap, so you need to increase the total heap size as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2GB of memory and I run tomcat with settings -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m. This usually runs fine.