# Developing With Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I'm running TC 6 in "development mode", eg. the application classes are changing constantly and I want to see the latest version with minimal hassle.

For a while I was using the TC HTML 'manager' application to reload; this worked up to a point, but I kept getting OOM errors after a while. Surfing suggested that TC has a leak when reloading this way. Plus it was a hassle, the extra step after compiling every time.

So I switched to setting 'reloadable true' in the context.xml file. This worked up to a point and didn't require any extra steps, but again I keep getting OOM errors (less frequently, but still many times a day). More surfing suggests that there may be TC leaks in here also.

If I run the app with 'reloadable true' but don't recompile anything, or with 'reloadable false', it runs forever (and VisualVM thinks it is OK memory-wise).

So I am kind of coming to the conclusion that every time I recompile a class I should fully restart TC. This is a huge pain but maybe better than random periodic OOM crashes. Just wondered if anyone had any better ideas. Maybe I should try a different container.

Cheers and thanks!

---

Thanks a lot for the responses. JRebel looks like a great plan, I will try that; it appears to be designed specifically to solve this problem, which suggests that I am not making it up, and it's cheap enough that if it's a scam, no big deal.

The app does a few simple, standard MySQL calls via ConnectorJ, and the default out of the box memory allocation. Frankly though I don't see how either of these things are relevant, since the app behaves fine as long as no reloading occurs.

Thanks again. Once again, I can't believe how useful SO is!

Comment: Could you post the JVM memory settings you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat class reloading used to be [buggy](http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java) - and the OOM is the manifestation of that. [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/) is much more reliable in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009042/what-free-jvm-implementation-has-the-best-permgen-handling) useful. I remember seeing a question here that suggested using jRockit to solve this issue but I cannot remember where...I'll search and update this answer when I find it.

Actually it was [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) which promises to solve this problem. I haven't used it myself so I can't say how valid the claim is but I am considering it...

Answer (score 0):

We ended up with scripts to just redeploy in Tomcat - build from source control, shut down tomcat, remove stale files from tomcat, deploy new war, restart tomcat, check tomcat logs for errors.

Otherwise we got the memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything special in your application - e.g. starting your own (non daemon) threads, or using libraries which does so ? Atleast in that case you get leaks.

I'm developing using eclipse, having tomcat managed by eclipse for development. Tomcat auto reloads the application after every compile - I've not yet experienced any memory growth or leaks, nor when I have a setup for developing against a remote tomcat devel server - deploying the app from an ant script. Allthough it did leak when I started using java.util.concurrent.Executors which(by default) creates non-daemon threads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to use JRebel and JSF http://przemek-nowak.pl/2010/10/jrebel-czyli-jak-przyspieszyc-prace-programisty/, may be useful to someone.